# Ng-options in angularjs to show the selected value from the json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, select, drop-down-menu

I am using angular js select to display the name which is of type json array.using the below code i could display the name when a name is selected it stores a json object which moves to the next page but when i come back to the select page i would like to show the previous selected name but it shows an empty field;

Html:

```
<select class="formSelect"
              ng-model="vm.product.farmer"
              ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
              ng-options="farmer as farmer.name for farmer in vm.load.selectedFarmers">
                    <option value="" selected hidden />
                </select>
```

Ctrl:

```
vm.load.selectedFarmers = getFarmers();
function getFarmers () {
  farmers = [
    { name: 'Nidhin', id: 22 },
    { name: 'Sathish', id: 10 },
    { name: 'Kumar', id: 23 },
    { name: 'Rajkumar', id: 24 }
  ];
  return farmers;
}
```

when moving from first page to the second page the select has an object like {name: 'Nidhin', id: 22 }

While coming back from the second page to the first page how can i show the selected name?

Comment: I think when you come back to the page your `ng-model` which is `vm.product.farmer` is null. Try to print it out using `{{vm.product.farmer}}` somewhere to ensure it has a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the position of your selected data based on the position you can change the ng-model value

```
if (CommonService.isValid(vm.product.farmer)) {
    vm.currentPosition = vm.load.selectedFarmers.findIndex(function (item) {
      return item.id === vm.product.farmer.id;
    });
  } else {
    vm.currentPosition = -1;
  }
  vm.product.farmer = vm.load.selectedFarmers[vm.currentPosition];
```

Try the above code and check whether it solves your problem.